# How to do an action when an element is added to a page using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, live

When I add something of the class "myClass" I want to call a function on this element.

It would be something in the lines of:

```
jQuery(".error_message").live("load",function(){
  alert("test"+this);
});
```

... except this doesn't exist.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: How are you adding the elements to the DOM?

Comment: I load a some new html via ajax and throw it in the DOM

Comment: There are different ways I could add these elements, that's why I'd like to avoid to have a callback on these functions.

Comment: This is something I've wanted to know for Greasemonkey scripts too...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short, direct answer to your question would be "no can do." But from your comment a few minutes ago, I see that you want to add elements in different ways and have one unified method of handling these newly added items. May I suggest another approach? [Trigger custom events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata).

The way it would work is like this: everywhere you load the error-message element, you add one line when it's done:

```
 $('.error_message').trigger('load');
```

Now your .live('load'...) thing will work.

Comment: That's a very interesting answer. I'm not really sure if that's what I'm looking for... it looks a bit hacky. But I don't know jquery enought to tell hacky from amazing. So, would you say this is a good practice?

Comment: I'll vouch for it - there's also a good article on event pooling that talks about this on a document level: http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/index.php/2008/12/event-pooling-with-jquery-using-bind-and-trigger-managing-complex-javascript/

Comment: any idea how .live() does what it does?

Comment: This only worked for me when I used "loaded" instead of "load" v1.9.X