# How to bind to a non-user initiated function using jQuery.on()

Tags: jquery

With the new[ish] .on syntax it's very easy to bind to events that the user triggers. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-div', function() {
    alert("You clicked it!");
});
```

But what about binding to things the user might not trigger?

```
$(document).on('somethingaddedtoDOM', '#my-element', function() {
    alert("Nothing");
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle to give a better idea of what I'm talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/NedRW/3/

---

Ok, here's a similar problem. Let's say I want to dynamically add a slider into the DOM. sudoSlider for this example. Let's use Mustache.js and the Mustache.jquery plugin:

Html

```
...
<div id="slider-target-container">
</div>
...
```

View model:

```
var viewModel = [
    {
        image: "path-to-image"
    },
    {
        image: "path-to-image"
    },
    {
        image: "path-to-image"
    }
];
```

Mustache template

```
<script type="text/html" id="slider-template">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul>
           <li>{{image}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.Mustache.addFromDom();
    var html = $('#slider-template');
    $('#slider-target-container').appendTo(mustache.render(html, viewModel);
});
```

Now, obviously I need to call the sudoSlider plugin on my newly created slider HTML. But I can't do that with the new .on() method, as far as I can tell

What used to work:

```
$('#slider').live(function() {
    $(this).sudoSlider();
});
```

But now, as far as I can tell, I have no way if a new item was added to the dom (and if so, with a specific identifier) so I've no way to bind plugins to things that might not exist yet. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Exactly like this... I don't understand your problem. Since the user does not create an event that triggers the handler, you'd have to trigger it programmatically. But since your question is about binding, and not triggering, I'm confused. What is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', "#tester", function() {
    alert("Clicked");
    $('<div id="tester-2"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $('#tester-2').css("background", "red");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was tired when I wrote that. Basically what I mean is that div-2 would be dynamically inserted into the dom. I've edited the fiddle accordingly if you could look at it again http://jsfiddle.net/NedRW/3/

Comment: @Hg3 please describe what you're _actually_ trying to do, not the problems with the method you incorrectly think does it.  Google for "XY problem"

Comment: What I'm actually talking about would involve pasting a lot of code in here. I was trying to simplify it as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

The live documentation on jquery describes how `.on` replaces `.live` well:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Looking at your example above I think a number of:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
       <li>{{image}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

are added to

```
<div id="slider-target-container"></div>
```

This will create elements with the same id (#slider) so let's make it:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
       <li>{{image}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

instead.

```
$(document).on("click", "#slider-target-container .slider", function(){
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Is then hopefully what you are looking for?

If you would like to trigger something whenever a specific new element is added to the dom you could use a custom trigger:

http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/index.php/2008/12/event-pooling-with-jquery-using-bind-and-trigger-managing-complex-javascript/

from

[How to do an action when an element is added to a page using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490313/how-to-do-an-action-when-an-element-is-added-to-a-page-using-jquery)

Both `.bind` .and `.live` have been replaced by `.on` as above.

Comment: That's still binding to a click event. In this case for slider navigation I would assume. The question is, how to bind a plugin to an entire tree that's not there?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490313/how-to-do-an-action-when-an-element-is-added-to-a-page-using-jquery and http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/index.php/2008/12/event-pooling-with-jquery-using-bind-and-trigger-managing-complex-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```
But what about binding to things the user might not trigger?
```

I did not fully understand your question, but based on what I understood, I am listing solution as below:

```
// add a click handler to an element that doesn't yet exist
$('document').delegate('#contentToBeAdded', 'click', function(e) {
    // do something
    // example use case would be content added using AJAX or from any manipulation user has not triggered.
});

// even handle a custom event for an element
$('document').delegate('#contentToBeAdded', 'custom-event', function(e) {
    // do something and in this case I assume 'somethingAddedToDOM' is a custom event thrown by user
});
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: If the functionality in question is DOM change then you can listen to Mutation events [onpropertychange event for our eternal love IE]