# Bootstrap scaffolding customization with CKeditor, add class to div row element programmatically on insert

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

When creating a scaffolding template with Bootstrap inside of a Ckeditor, how do I add a custom class to the div which already has the class "row"? I would want this to appear automatically no matter what scaffolding template I choose

So I would want these

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
</div>
```

To automatically appear as these

```
<div class="row CUSTOMCLASS">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row CUSTOMCLASS">
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="row customclass">`

Comment: I should have made it clear that this is through CKEditor, so I would want to display it automatically

Comment: That definitely would have helped.

Comment: Is it the same `CUSTOMCLASS` for each `row`?

Comment: Yes, I would like the same CUSTOMCLASS for every row

Comment: Hmmm...you could use jQuery `$( ".row" ).addClass( "CUSTOMCLASS" );`, but you'll also have to use a trigger event when another `.row` div is added. This may lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490313/how-to-do-an-action-when-an-element-is-added-to-a-page-using-jquery